# Rewrite a file with PHP using HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms, url-rewriting

So I'm working on a little php file that is supposed to alter a specific file for the user. It gets the contents of the file and puts them into a textarea within a form. How can I make it so any edits done within this textarea will be rewritten to the file on the server? And even better, would I be able to allow the user to only edit certain lines, and have only those lines be rewritten?

Here's my code so far:

```
<?php
$filename = "../tree_c/index.php";
//$fp = fopen ($filename, "w"); <- doesn't seem to work for it opens empty file.
$contents = file_get_contents($filename);
/*
if (isset($_POST['field'])) {
    // something here to rewrite the file.
*/
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <textarea name="field"><?php echo $contents ?></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Comment: You are going to need a second PHP page that can process the edits made and save them. Don't forget, PHP is server side only. You would need to use JavaScript to handle the user interface and send data back for PHP to process

Comment: You need some Javascript - Ajax if you want every change in the client-side saved in server.

Comment: Oh, when I said you need a second PHP page, that is the less confusing way. One page generates HTML to edit your file, then a second one is used to save it. It is perfectly possible to merge the two

Answer (score 1):

This should work fairly easily:

```
if (isset($_POST['field'])) {
  file_put_contents($filename, $_POST['field']);
}
```

Comment: wouldn't this just append the field contents to the end?

Comment: No. As per http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php : "If filename does not exist, the file is created. Otherwise, the existing file is overwritten, unless the FILE_APPEND flag is set". If you don't specify FILE_APPEND you're fine.

Comment: Perfect thanks! Now, is there any way to only allow certain lines for editing, and rewrite only those lines?

Comment: controlling what lines are to be edit it best done through JavaScript. Though you could use PHP to extract those lines out, and have a series of paragraphs for read-only lines and form entry fields to writeable lines. You will need to validate it through PHP though, just to make sure no tinkering has been done on the web page

Answer (score 1):

```
        $datafile = "Files.txt";
        $fp = fopen($datafile, "r");
        $textdata= fgets($fp, 1024);
        $text = '"'.$textdata.'"';
        $this->set('text',$text);
        if(!empty($this->data))
        {
           $datas = $this->data['data']['text'];  //(your Textarea name)
           $myFile = "Files.txt";
           $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
           fwrite($fh, $datas);
           fclose($fh);
        }
```

hope this ll help you....